# Incorrect FileInputStream KmlLayer

Tags: android, kml

In my class **MapsActivity.java** I have created, in addition to onCreate:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    try {
        layer = new KmlLayer(mMap, generateNoteOnStorage(getApplicationContext(), "kmll.kml", contenuto), getApplicationContext());
        //layer = new KmlLayer(mMap, R.raw.kmll, getApplicationContext());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        layer.addLayerToMap();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

and

```
public FileInputStream generateNoteOnStorage(Context context, String sFileName, String sBody) {
        try {
            File root = new File(Environment.getRootDirectory(), "kmlfiles");
            if (!root.exists()) {
                root.mkdirs();
            }
            File gpxfile = new File(root, sFileName);
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile);
            writer.append(sBody);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            Toast.makeText(context, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return new FileInputStream(gpxfile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I can't understand why this code is wrong. I'm pretty sure that it's due to FileInputStream procedure (also because I'm not so friendly with them).
This is the error:
[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekmqi.png)

I also tried to copy kmll.kml (the generated file) to res/raw and then, instead of `generateNoteOnStorage(getApplicationContext(), "kmll.kml", contenuto)` I replaced it with `R.raw.kmll` and it worked.

Comment: `catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }`. Add a Toast() to inform the user. And then return. Now you continue adding a layer as if nothing has happened.

Comment: `Environment.getRootDirectory()`You cannot use that system directory for your app. mkdirs() will fail. But you are not checking itd return value so you dont know. Display a toast too if it fails. And return then

Comment: What I should use?

Comment: I replaced it with getExternalStorageDirectory() and it works. Do you have some other advice? However thanks

Comment: Add a Toast in every catch block to inform the user. And do not continue if there is one but stop.